# Other representation of the Lagrange remainder

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

so far I've only seen this representation of the Lagrange remainder
$R_n=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $a$. $(i)$

Now I came across this representation:
$R_n=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(x_{0}+\vartheta (x-x_0))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$ for $\vartheta\in(0,1).  $$(ii)$

I can't figure out how to get $(ii)$ from $(i)$.

About $(i)$ I know that this comes from the mean value theorem for integrals, but I don't really know how to interpret this.
The mean value theorem for derivatives states, that you can find one point $c$in an intervall $[a,b]$ so that $f'(c) = \dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$, which says (graphically) that the derivative of $c$ is equal to the average slope of $f$ from $a$ to $b$. What is the (graphical) statement one can get from the mvt for integrals.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just read carefully what you have written yourself: In your first representation, $c$ is **some point between $x_0$ and $x$** (should be $x_0$ and not $a$).
Now your second representation simply says that your $c = x_0 + \vartheta(x-x_0)$ for some $\vartheta \in (0,1)$, which is also just some point between $x$ and $x_0$.

Regarding your second question, I suppose you refer to the special case of the mvt for integrals, where  $$\int_a^bf(x) \ \mathrm dx = f(\xi)(b-a), \quad \xi \in [a,b]$$

A geometrical interpretation is that the area beneath the curve of $f$ between $a$ and $b$ is equal to the area of a rectangle with one length $b-a$ and the other length some function value between $a$ and $b$.

[image]